# i have problem with jquery slide up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div and inside of div i want to fill it with paragraph that i get from server and it may be 1 or 100 paragraphs.

i want to just show the first one and the rest wont be shown and by click div slide down and show the rest.

```
<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

var slideStatus = false;

 if (!slideStatus) {
   $(".card-text-paragraph").animate({ height: "100%" }, "slow");
    console.log(slideStatus);
    slideStatus = true;
    console.log(slideStatus);
  } else {
    $(".card-text-paragraph").animate({ height: "90px" }, "slow");
    console.log(slideStatus);
    slideStatus = false;
    console.log(slideStatus);
  }
```

it slides up smoth but wont slide down smoth to 100% if i give it in px it will be ok but i want to go to 100%

any one can help me ?

Comment: try using slideDown() and slideUp event

Comment: Did you try using height in `vh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another option `slideToggle`

```js
function clickfunc(){
   $(".card-text-paragraph").slideToggle();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clickfunc()">click</button>
<div class="card-text-paragraph" style="">
<p>.</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>....</p>
<p>.....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, for transition you need to keep unit of height same.

Try this

```
<div class="content">
<p></p>
<p></p>
....
....
....
<p></p>
</div>
```

Js Code:

```
var heightOfContent = $('.content').height(),
    expandContentStatus = false;

    $('.content').height('90px');

    $('.content').on('click', function() {
       if(expandContentStatus) {
           $(this).height(heightOfContent);
       } else {
           $(this).height('90px');
       }
    })
```

Thing is first you need to store actual height of **div.content** element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideUp & slideDown` method

```js
var slideStatus = false;
function clickfunc(){
 if (!slideStatus) {
   $(".card-text-paragraph").slideUp();
    slideStatus = true;
  } else {
    $(".card-text-paragraph").slideDown();
    slideStatus = false;
  }
 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clickfunc()">click</button>
<div class="card-text-paragraph" style="">
<p>.</p>
<p>..</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>....</p>
<p>.....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this will hide all p elements i want to show first p element on slide up